# Image-view not showing in xml defined Frame-Layout on Android application

Tags: android, xml, matrix, imageview, android-framelayout

I have a frame-layout defined in xml a follows:

```
//pseudo code
<FrameLayout
android:height = "match_parent" // same for width
android:background="@android:color/white"
padding = "20dp"
id = "polygraph"
layout_gravity="center"/>
```

I access this xml view via code as such:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
frameInflate = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.mframe,null);
frar = (FrameLayout)frameInflate.findViewById(R.id.polygraph);
```

I create the following image-view dynamically but somehow it doesn't show inside this frame-layout which is one of many views inside another frame-layout that holds all the views of my User-Interface

```
view1 = new ImageView(this);
view1.setAdjustViewBounds(false);
matrix = new Matrix();
view1.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.Matrix);//I have tried: ScaleType.Center it did not work at all
view1.setImageMatrix(matrix);
view1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
params11= new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(200,300,Gravity.CENTER);
view1.setLayoutParams(params11);
DummyDraw drawD = new DummyDraw(this);
view1.setImageDrawable(drawD);

frar.addView(view1);

//somewhere down on onWindowsFocusChange()
frar.invalidate();  //try to invalidate to see if it will show the imageview
```

No image-view shows at all. I have tried different ways, such as:

```
frar.addView(view1,params11); //did not work
//instead of view1.setImageDrawable
view1.setBackground(drawD); //nothing
view1.setImageResource(R.drawable.somerandomdrawable);//nothing
```

I have no idea why this view isn't showing. Could it be the drawable "drawD"? If it is this drawable, then why isn't showing at least the background color "gray"
which I set in the code? I have tried to get rid of the ScaleType.Matrix to something else, such as ScaleType.Center, but nothing seems to work.

Any advice or suggestions will be appreciated

thanks

Comment: Why do you want to inflate it? I would suggest to first try out a very simple layout only with that item, to see where the problem is (for instance, usually you should define the id like ```android:id="@+id/my_id"``` ... read what the +id part does). This way you can see if the problem is in the xml. If not, it's most likely the inflater, but again you need to understand what you are doing and why. Inflate only if you need something programmatically created, and if you've a good reason for it. Hope it helps!

Comment: in `frameInflate = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.mframe,null);` you are passing `null` as a root / parent, so you have to add `frameInflate` to some other `ViewGroup`, otherwise you see nothing - you can always check your UI tree by running `adb shell dumpsys activity top`

Comment: @pskink I see what you are saying. I think that's where the problem is. But what can I pass instead of null. The parent layout that is. Let me investigate.

Comment: what does `adb shell dumpsys activity top` show?

Comment: I don't know how to use the adb with android studio.. sorry @pskink. But, I know that's where the problem is.. I must convert my entire xml layout as a viewgroup object and pass it instead of null

Comment: @pskink But how can I access the adb shell dumpsys?

Comment: from the command line? https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html

Comment: am running the app now.. I just created a framelayout object that contains the entire UI. I think it will work.. I passed it instead of null @pskink

Comment: my entire UI id is "frame" I created a FrameLayout object based on this id, and passed it instead of null, but it didn't work. I will have to investigate the dumpsys.. Let me see how to access it. @pskink

Comment: View > Tool Windows > Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I had ran into the same problem a few months ago. But I did forget how to handle it. LayoutInflater wasn't needed to solve the problem. Seems like I can't do this call inside onCreate() "(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.polygraph)" and then try to add my programmatically created image-view to my xml layout element. It gave me a null pointer exception all the time.

Moving both calls way after the layout pass, such as on onStart() or onWindowsFocusChanged() works well. The image-view is added to the xml frame-layout, which in the end it works well for my app, since I had the intentions of adding the image-view well beyond the layout pass.

Comment: you can do that inside `onCreate`, no need for custom `onWindowsFocusChanged` method

Comment: I have done the findViewById calls inside onCreate(), but try to add a view to a layout that you instatiated via a findViewById call inside onCreate and it gives a null pointer exception. @pskink

Comment: `findViewById` returns null inside `onCreate` but not-null inside `onWindowsFocusChanged`?? are you sure you called `findViewById` after calling `setContentView(R.layout.your_main_layout_file)`?

Comment: that's where the problem was.. I was calling findViewById before setContentView. That's why setContentView should be one of your first few lines of code on onCreate() if you rely on an xml layout. @pskink These are errors that I have encountered in the past, but since its been so long, they just flew by me today.

Comment: @pskink you seem to know a bit about android-drawables. Now, that I have resolved this issue, do you know a good way to pinch-zoom into a drawable that lies inside an imageview. I am trying to follow a tutorial but is not doing what is expected.

Comment: Use scaleType = matrix